# Patentability of language improvement

Tags: patentability, microsoft, data-processing-language, improvement

Is it possible to patent an improvement of a Programming language ( new method to write it) in order to sell the improvement to Microsoft or others. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes possible if algorithm is new

Comment: Could you define "new method to write it?" I don't need (or want) to hear details *about* said method, but do you mean that you've written a new compiler? A new algorithm in that language? A new language feature? Or something else?

Comment: HI  Matthew Haugen :

 I Have written A new language feature. Wish to hear from you . THanks

Comment: Hi Pushpak Singh:
 
I don't know how to define algorithm. The principle of my invention is to make language better readable even for foreign people. Thus I have written a new features 
Thanks dear Pushpak

Comment: Not to rain on your parade, but while certain things can be patented, if you don't know what an algorithm is, then it would be prudent not to "hold your breath" about anyone buying your idea... patented or not.

Comment: I would like to help you in case you feel that you cant characterize your invention, but to make it project a new and non-obvious method should be in your hand.